# Regex to match two or more spaces

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse some attributes from a modem's AT output. My regex is as follow:

```
([^:]*):\s*([^\s]*)
```

Sample output as follow:

```
LTE SSC1 bw  : 20 MHz           LTE SSC1 chan: 2850
LTE SSC2 state:INACTIVE         LTE SSC2 band: B20
LTE SSC2 bw  : 10 MHz           LTE SSC2 chan: 6300
EMM state:     Registered       Normal Service
RRC state:     RRC Connected
IMS reg state: NOT REGISTERED   IMS mode:    Normal
```

This mostly works ok but not so well where an attribute's value has more characters after the first whitespace. For example, the match "LTE SSC2 bw" has a group 2 value of "10" when it should be "10 MHz".

Ideally I need the regex to match exactly the attributes, and group the value for it.

Hope this makes sense and thanks for your help.

Comment: [The metacharacter “\\s” matches spaces and + indicates the occurrence of the spaces one or more times, therefore, the regular expression \\S+ matches all the space characters (single or multiple).](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-replace-multiple-spaces-in-a-string-using-a-single-space-using-java-regex#:~:text=The%20metacharacter%20%E2%80%9C%5C%5Cs%E2%80%9D,spaces%20with%20a%20single%20space.)

Comment: @robert I think you meant `\\s+` not `\\S+`?

Comment: @Bohemian: It's a direct copy/paste of a passage in the linked article.  If there's an error, it's an error in the original article.

Answer (score 0):

If there is always at least two spaces between the key-value pairs you can use

```
([^:\s][^:]*):[^\S\r\n]*(\S+(?:[^\S\r\n]\S+)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BS3ABo/1).

*Details*:

- `([^:\s][^:]*)` - Group 1: a char other than whitespace and `:` and then zero or more non-`:` chars
- `:` - a colon
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - zero or more whitespaces other than CR and LF chars
- `(\S+(?:[^\S\r\n]\S+)*)` - Group 2: one or more non-whitespaces, then zero or more repetitions of a whitespace other than CR and LF chars and then one or more non-whitespace chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this regex:

```
(?<attribute>[A-Z]{3} [^:]+): *(?<value1>.*?)(?> {2,}|$)(?<value2>[^:]+$)?
```

The groups you have are the following:

- Group 1 **attribute**: will contain the attribute name
- Group 2 **value1**: will contain the attribute value
- Group 3 **value2**: will contain the optional attribute second value (for the fourth line)

Explanation:

- `(?<attribute>[A-Z]{3} [^:]+)`: Group 1

  - `[A-Z]{3}`: three uppercase letters
  - : a space
  - `[^:]+`: any combination of characters other than colon
- `: *`: colon + any number of spaces
- `(?<value1>.*?)`: Group 2

  - `.*?`: any character (in lazy modality, so that it tries to match the least amount that can match)
- `(?> {2,}|$)`: Positive lookahead that matches

  - `{2,}`: two or more spaces (end of first inline attribute:value)
  - `|`: or
  - `$`: end of string (end of second inline attribute:value)
- `(?<value2>[^:]+$)?`: Group 3

  - `[^:]+`: any combination of characters other than colon
  - `$`: end of string

You can call each group by their respective names.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/L89HOo/1).